# How do you get the time interval for UIDatePicker in UIDatePickerModeCountDownTimer mode?

Tags: iphone

I have a `UIViewController` with a `UIDatePicker` datePicker property.  I have configured it in Interface Builder to have a `UIDatePicker` in "Timer" mode and to have it call the `datePickerValueDidChange:` method of the view controller when the "Value Changed" event occurs.  The code in the view controller looks like this:

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
  NSLog(@"datePicker: %@", datePicker);
  NSLog(@"datePicker.datePickerMode: %d", datePicker.datePickerMode);
}
```

And when the view loads, you see this in the log

```
datePicker: <UIDatePicker: 0x3b03660; frame = (0 61; 320 216); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x3b033a0>>
datePicker.datePickerMode: 3
```

So that means the date picker is initialized and the mode is `UIDatePickerModeCountDownTimer`.  When I change the value by moving one of the scroll wheels, it calls this method:

```
- (IBAction) datePickerValueDidChange:(id)sender {
  NSLog(@"datePicker.countDownDuration: %@", datePicker.countDownDuration);
}
```

And the output in the log is:

```
datePicker.countDownDuration: (null)
```

Why is it null?  Is this not the way to get the value for the hours/minutes the user has selected?  If not, how can you get those values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

countDownDuration is an NSTimeInterval (really a double). To print it out, you'll need to use

```
NSLog(@"datePicker.countDownDuration: %f", datePicker.countDownDuration);
```